# repeat array until certain length groupby pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

In R data table there is a way to repeat a vector in combination with the length of the final vector. For example I created the variable called 'period' which is repetition of the vector q.

R code:

```
require(data.table)
q = c(1:3)
test = data.table(IDx = c(rep('42', 5) , rep('76', 3), rep('43', 3), rep('5', 2)),
                  IDy = c(rep('A', 5) , rep('A', 3), rep('B', 3) , rep('C',2)))
test[, period := rep(q, length.out = .N), by =c('IDx','IDy')]

   IDx IDy period
 1:  42   A      1
 2:  42   A      2
 3:  42   A      3
 4:  42   A      1
 5:  42   A      2
 6:  76   A      1
 7:  76   A      2
 8:  76   A      3
 9:  43   B      1
10:  43   B      2
```

I'm trying to replicate this function in python but I'm a bit stuck. The cumcount function could only be applied by considering the sequence q which should start over once the last index has been reached.

```
q = [1,2,3]
valuesX = ['42'] * 5 + ['76'] * 3 + ['43'] * 3 + ['5'] * 2 
valuesY = ['A'] * 5 + ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 3 + ['C'] * 2
test = pd.DataFrame({'IDx':valuesX,
                    'IDy':valuesY})

print(test.groupby(['IDx','IDy']).cumcount()+1)
```

Attempted approach,

```
def repeat(seq, ind):
    length = len(ind.index)
    print(length)
    multiple, remainder = divmod(length, len(seq))
    test['t'] = seq * multiple + seq[:remainder]

print(test.groupby(['IDx']).apply(lambda x: repeat(q, x)))
```

Comment: Are you looking for `groupby.cumcount`?

Comment: No, I tried to use that but there is no end value. The cumcount should stop and repeat it self once the last index has been reach

Comment: `df.groupby(['IDx', 'IDy']).cumcount().mod(3).add(1)` seems to do the job.

Comment: I added a generic approach to map values from an arbitrary iterable `q`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`mod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mod.html), then use numpy indexing (you could also [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values):

```
import numpy as np

s = test.groupby(['IDx', 'IDy']).cumcount().mod(len(q))

test['period'] = np.array(q)[s]
```

Output:

```
   IDx IDy  period
0   42   A       1
1   42   A       2
2   42   A       3
3   42   A       1
4   42   A       2
5   76   A       1
6   76   A       2
7   76   A       3
8   43   B       1
9   43   B       2
10  43   B       3
11   5   C       1
12   5   C       2
```